# Particular tabbar item hide when app loads in Tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have added the following in Appdelegate.m file to hide particular tab bar item ("Hai") in the tab bar controller (created by IB). But it did not work.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"Hai"]) {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to hide a tab bar item, but you could create an array of view controllers and exclude this particular one from that array. Later when the tab should be visible, [set the view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated:) for the tab bar controller again and include that view controller this time.

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```