# How can I hide a tab Bar Item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have added a tab bar (UITabBar) in my iPhone application.
I want to hide a tab Bar item through code? Is it possible?

Comment: You don't have to add a dot (.) in front of a question mark (?). ;-)

Comment: Check this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116054/particular-tabbar-item-hide-when-app-loads-in-tab-bar-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .h file declare a

```
 UIBarButtonItem *mybutton

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *mybutton;
```

attache it to your UiBarButton in IB

then in .m file do

```
  @synthesize mybutton;

  mybutton.hidden=YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

**U can Hide BY USING below Code**

```
  for(id object in appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.subviews)
    {
        [object setHidden:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
```

Comment: You know that this will hide bottom bar only when a viewcontroller is pushed in it's navigationcontroller stack, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using storyboard, you can set property of that storyboard "Hide Bottom Bar on Push"
on the attributes inspector (the forth small item look like the face of human )

Answer (score 0):

Just set alpha for tab you need to hide

```
UIView *tabItem = self.tabBar.subviews[0];
tabItem.alpha = 0.0;
```