# Hide a Tab bar Item in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar controller with a logginViewController, and I want to hide the tab bar item related to logginViewController and show a different tab bar item with a different ViewController

I'm working using Storyboard in a tab bar based app for iPhone

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150389/how-can-i-hide-a-tab-bar-item) but it doesn't work (Xcode don't allow me to use the "hide" option)

Please, any help on how I can do it in Xcode 4 will be great!

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I like to suppose, that you subclass your TabBarController.

Via Protocol/Delegate you're able to work with data from your loggingViewController (maybe, a button get's clicked to hide the TabBarItem).
Implement that protocol to your TabBarController and so you're able to receive those protocol-methods to add/hide/delete the Items easily.

Try it out! Or further questions?

Comment: Well, the idea is: I have a total of 6 tab bar items and i don't want to show them all at the same time, so, when i press the log gin button, the log gin tab bar item will disappear and the last one will appear, but i don't know how to do this